# seamlessly automount ecryptfs using ssh key auth?

Tags: ssh, automount, ecryptfs

Is there any way to automount ecryptfs mounts when logging in via ssh key and without additional user interaction?

For example, is there any ssh extension that tells the client to decrypt some remote stuff like the ecryptfs passwd by using its private key?

Answer (score 0):

An old thread, but I couldn't find an answer, so I'll post what I did.

It is possible, but it is not so simple. You must know what you're doing, so I'll post only guidelines, not the copy/paste solution.

On host:

1. Give `write` permission on `unmounted` $HOME
2. Copy `encryptfs-mount-private` script to `unmounted` $HOME, and change `LOGNAME` to accept parameter (a password)
3. Make script (i.e. mySSHlogin)that'll

   a) copy `.XAuthority` from `unmounted` $HOME to some common location (i.e. `/tmp`)

   b) mount ecryptefs (2.) with password given as param and `cd ~`

   c) make backup of `.XAuthority` in `mounted` $HOME

   d) move `.Xauthority` from common location to `mounted` $HOME

   e) start shell

   f) restore original `.Xauthority` file in `mounted` $HOME

On remote:

1. run `ssh` that exec that script (3.) with supplied password on host

(`gnome-terminal -x ssh -Y me@host -t /home/me/mySSHlogin somePassword`)

Security is somewhat compromised by leaving `.Xauthority` in `unmounted` $HOME (what could be solved by moving instead of copying in 2., but `xauth` shows a notice than), but should be fine on local network.

Also, concurrent access through ssh and directly on host can show unpredictable in certain conditions (what might be solved by appending `.Xauthority` from unmounted to `mounted` `.Xauthority`, which should than be cleaned periodically).

As I said, those are just guidelines.
And, as always, `backup`, `backup`, `backup`.

Of course, all this can be avoided if you're using password for ssh, and `sshpass` that supplies the password, so you don't have to type it.

Comment: **This is horribly insecure because it stores your password in plain text** on your "remote" system.  The question asks for the actual SSH key to be able to generate the password so it is not stored on either side. This would have to be a challenge-response kind of system, e.g. with mySSHlogin containing a challenge (a string of perhaps 4096 random characters) and a script on the "remote" system that uses the SSH key to sign it. That signature would then be used by mySSHlogin as the ecryptfs password. The problem with this proposal is that *only* that SSH key can unlock the ecryptfs directory.